# Using class and lists in a very specific instance and adding the properties of a class in the list of another class

Tags: python, list, class

#so basically I have set up both of my classes here:

```
class item():
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class person():
    def __init__(self, name, money):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money
        self.items = []
```

#And then I have the actual objects here:

```
sword = item("Sword", 10)
bow = item("Bow", 15)
flame = item("Flame", 20)

player = person("", 0)
```

#I appended the sword and bow to the player items list, but as an example not the flame:

```
player.items.append(sword)
player.items.append(bow)
```

```
#Add the value of all items on the persons item list, Best I can think of is player.money += player.items[ALL ITEMS AVAILABLE].value

#The idea is that not all items are appended to the list but I can still add them to make a sum to 'buy them', and add more later...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a little restructuring of the code to make it a bit more OO. Then you just need a function for the Person class that will return the total value of all its Items

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, money=0):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money
        self.items = []
    def additem(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def get_total_value(self):
        return sum(i.value for i in self.items)

person = Person('gavviegoo')

person.additem(Item('Sword', 10))
person.additem(Item('Bow', 15))

print(person.get_total_value())
```

**Output:**

```
25
```